# jQuery slideDown & then slideUp on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple `.slideDown` function:

```
$globalTabs.find('.seeMore a').live("click", function(){
     $globalTabs.find(".allTabs").slideDown('slow');
 });
```

When a user clicks on an `<a>` in `.allTabs` ,`.allTabs` does a `.slideUp`.

What I want to do, is if a user has not clicked anything in `.allTabs` and the mouse is no longer within `.allTabs`, then a timer initiates to wait x amount of time and then do the `.slideUp`. Additionally, if the mouse enters `.allTabs` again before the `.slideUp` triggers - then the timer is stopped and resets when the mouse is moved outside of `.allTabs`

Not sure how to approach. Any help would be appreciated.

base markup:

```
<div class="allTabs">
   <a href="#">link 1</a>
   <a href="#">link 2</a>
   <a href="#">link 3</a>
   <a href="#">link 4</a>
</div>
```

and:

```
<li class="seeMore"><a href="#">see more</a></li>
```

Comment: @Jason, Should it be read as `.allTabs` does a `.slideDown`, not a `.slideUp` ?

Comment: @caligula - it does a slidedown, and then when you click in `allTabs` it does a slideUp. I also just saw that our site is loading hoverIntent - which may make this easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(function() {
    var $allTabs = $globalTabs.find(".allTabs");
    var timer;
    $globalTabs.find('.seeMore a').live("click", function(){
        $allTabs.slideDown('slow');
    });
    $allTabs.mouseout(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function() {$allTabs.slideUp()}, 3000);
    });
    $allTabs.mouseover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` functions, note that `live` method has been deprecated, you can use the `on` method instead.

```
var timeout;

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout)
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        var $this = $(this)    
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
           $this.slideUp('slow')         
        }, 500)
    },
}, ".allTabs")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72xSD/1/)

**Update:**

```
var timeout;

$(document).delegate(".allTabs", "mouseenter", function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
})

$(document).delegate(".allTabs", "mouseleave", function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $this.slideUp('slow')
    }, 1000)
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72xSD/2/)

Comment: would you mind if I ask you whether `mouseover` and `mouseout` also deprecated as `live`?

Comment: @caligula `live` is a jQuery method, but mouseover and mouseout are events, they cannot be deprecated, jQuery api has a list of deprecated methods and selectors http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: Did you mean that `live` is jQuery method, not object?

Comment: @caligula When you select an element by using jQuery, you have a jQuery object, objects have methods and properties, `live` is a method of jQuery object.

Comment: Our jQuery version does not support `.on` (1.6.4)

Comment: @Jason Is there any reason that you cannot use newer version?

Comment: our updates to jQuery follow our project release cycle. Enterprise/Corporate level ecommerce site. So, once/twice a year we may update jQuery (although most of us developers would like it to be with each major project).

Comment: @Jason Okay, I have updated the fiddle using `delegate` instead of `on` : http://jsfiddle.net/72xSD/2/

Answer (score 1):

Set a timer to do the `slideup` in the callback of the `slidedown` and on `mouseout` of `.allTabs`. Cancel the timer on `mouseover` on `.allTabs`.

```
var $timer;

function hideAllTabs() {
    $globalTabs.find(".allTabs").slideUp('slow');
}
$globalTabs.find('.seeMore a').live("click", function(){
    $globalTabs.find(".allTabs").slideDown('slow', function() {
        $timer = setTimeout(hideAllTabs, 1000);
    });
});
$globalTabs.find(".allTabs").live("mouseout",function() {
    $timer = setTimeout(hideAllTabs, 1000);
});
$globalTabs.find(".allTabs").live("mouseover",function() {
    clearTimeout($timer);
});
```

​

Comment: operates correctly one time but the click function on `.seeMore a` doesn't fire again