# Adding jQuery slideDown 1000ms after adding product

Tags: jquery, timer, slideup

I am designing this website http://www.dailydeliver.com/index.php

Here - you will see a cart. When you add a product - it goes to the cart. However, the cart remains open. The cart only closes when one hovers over the cart and then hovers out of it.

I want the cart to close automatically after opening for 1000ms when I add a product (press add to cart button). Below is the relevant code that opens the cart on adding a product, but it does not close it after a given time:

```
             $('.blockuserinfo-cart').addClass('close-cart');
                $(this).find(".blockuserinfo-cart").toggle(
                $('#cart_block').stop(true, true).slideDown(400),{
                duration:1500,
                easing: 'linear'
            });
```

Comment: How about adding delay() after updating the cart and then closing it?

Comment: @kren470 I found this answer relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118292/jquery-slidedown-then-slideup-on-timer?rq=1  but I do not know how to apply the answer to the above problem in terms of formulating code

Comment: @kren470 Please help me if possible by writing the full code relevant to above code.

Comment: wow. I just applied the delay method myself. Thank you @kren470

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by adding the .delay method. All credit goes to @Kren470 https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148796/kren470 for solving this for me. Pasting below the modified code that works:

```
$(this).find(".blockuserinfo-cart").toggle(
                    $('#cart_block').stop(true, true).slideDown(400).delay(2000).slideUp(400),{
                    duration:4500,
                    easing: 'linear'
                }
);
```